# ABPersonSetImageData works fine but contact's photo doesn't sync with Google

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiimage, abaddressbook, google-contacts-api

I've develop an App which set an image to my contact. It's working fine, my contact has the correct image in the iPhone AddressBook App.
I sync my AddressBook with Google and my contact's image doesn't sync with Google.
 
Why?? If I set an image using Edit in the AddressBook it's working fine?
What I'm doing wrong??
Cheers and Merry Christmas.

imgEscollida is and UIImage with the right photo contact to set.

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

ABRecordRef record = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, personaID);

if (record!=nil) {
    CFErrorRef *error = nil;

    ABPersonSetImageData(record, (CFDataRef)
                     (UIImagePNGRepresentation([self imgEscollida])), &error);

    if (ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error)) {
        NSLog(@"%s saved successfuly", _cmd);
    } 
    else {
        NSLog(@"%s something bad happen while saving", _cmd);
    }
}   
CFRelease(addressBook);
```